# Issues with multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

For some reason, in TeXmaker, I have no issues using `\multicolumn`, but `\multirow` simply just does not exist in my program.  I am trying to use both in a `tabular` environment and have the entire table built exactly how I want, except for the fact that I need to cover a couple of row with some of my entries.  I know how to write the code for it, but I get an error simply because it does not exist in my program.  Even if I try to put `\usepackage{multirow}` at the top, *that* produces an error!

Comment: give more information about the error message, your installed TeX distribution and your system

Comment: This is what I get when i try to put the package at the top :

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `multirow.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.10 \begin
{document}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

Comment: `multirow.sty` should be part of any TeX distribution. Which one do you have installed?

Comment: I have TeXmaker 3.1

Comment: @CSUNStudent: Herbert's question relates to whether you are running MiKTeX or TeX Live, or something else? Which operating system are you running on?

Comment: TeXmaker is an editor, no more no less. But not a TeX system

Comment: I am running TeXLive on my MAC laptop, which runs MAC OS X.

Comment: I am running TeXLive on my MAC laptop, which runs MAC OS X.

Comment: Problem has been fixed.  Although it was somehow left out of my system, I did find a way to drag multiro.sty into the proper folder so that it now operates just fine within my programs.  Thank you both for the help.